# Creating an unsecure endpoint for login on a secured Spring Boot RESTful API - WebConfig seemingly ignored

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

Thanks for checking out my question!

### What I'm trying to do:

I want my RESTful API to have an unsecured endpoint `/auth/login` that would allow a client to get a JWT token to be used for secure access.

### What I've done:

I have a RESTful API I created by essentially really quickly initializing using Spring Initializr with the Spring Security module enabled. After many hours of searching tutorials and guides (Spring Security is very difficult to grok) I've stumbled upon [this guide](https://www.toptal.com/java/rest-security-with-jwt-spring-security-and-java) that has a severe lack of code, but in the end I've found a [GitLab repo](https://gitlab.com/palmapps/jwt-spring-security-demo/tree/master) that has a complete implementation of that guide, so I've completely downloaded the `security` folder. The only problem is that the given implementation is configured  to have all URLs authenticated (as can be seen [here on line 60](https://gitlab.com/palmapps/jwt-spring-security-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/palmapps/myawesomeproject/security/config/WebSecurityConfig.java)), while I want to have `/auth/login` unsecured. As such, I have altered the configuration override to permit all requests for my desired unsecured endpoint:

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Configuration
@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {

        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(authenticationProvider));
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
        authenticationTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        authenticationTokenFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new JwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
        return authenticationTokenFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/auth/login/");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                // allow anonymous resource requests
                .antMatchers("/auth/login").permitAll()
                // All urls must be authenticated (filter for token always fires (/**)
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                // Call our errorHandler if authentication/authorisation fails
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                // don't create session
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS); //.and()
        // Custom JWT based security filter
        httpSecurity
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        // disable page caching
        httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
    }
}
```

### What's the problem?

For some reason, whenever I try to make a tokenless request to `/auth/login`, my server's response remains to be:

```
{"timestamp":1472057590171,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Authentication Failed: No JWT token found in request headers","path":"/auth/login"}
```

If I make a request with a token, as I would for a secured endpoint, the response is a 200 OK with all the proper response body.

It's almost as if the server is ignoring my configuration. In `JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.java` the constructer's `super` contains a string that indicated the path the filter is applied to. In my case it is applied to `/**`, or all paths. According to [this guide](http://www.baeldung.com/security-none-filters-none-access-permitAll), the configuration is supposed to override that.

### Extra data for debugging:

**JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Filter that orchestrates authentication by using supplied JWT token
 *
 * @author pascal alma
 */
public class JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    @Value("${jwt.header}")
    private String tokenHeader;

    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter() {
        super("/**");
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to authenticate request - basically just pass over to another method to authenticate request headers
     */
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String header = request.getHeader(this.tokenHeader);

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            throw new JwtTokenMissingException("No JWT token found in request headers");
        }

        String authToken = header.substring(7);

        JwtAuthenticationToken authRequest = new JwtAuthenticationToken(authToken);

        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }

    /**
     * Make sure the rest of the filterchain is satisfied
     *
     * @param request
     * @param response
     * @param chain
     * @param authResult
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws ServletException
     */
    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);

        // As this authentication is in HTTP header, after success we need to continue the request normally
        // and return the response as if the resource was not secured at all
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

**AuthController.java**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {
    @RequestMapping(path="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String response() {
        return "Hey!";
    }
}
```

**Spring Boot log (includes one unauthorized request to the supposedly unsecure `/auth/login`)**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.0.RELEASE)


2016-08-25 01:02:46.367  INFO 21486 --- [           main] com.BackendApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-08-25 01:02:46.423  INFO 21486 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@384ad17b: startup date [Thu Aug 25 01:02:46 HKT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-25 01:02:47.390  INFO 21486 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$afc52b37] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-08-25 01:02:47.424  INFO 21486 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4872f371] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-08-25 01:02:47.432  INFO 21486 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'objectPostProcessor' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-08-25 01:02:47.433  INFO 21486 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@57a48985' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-08-25 01:02:47.440  INFO 21486 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6d479623] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-08-25 01:02:47.448  INFO 21486 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-08-25 01:02:47.686  INFO 21486 --- [           main] org.xnio                                 : XNIO version 3.3.6.Final
2016-08-25 01:02:47.696  INFO 21486 --- [           main] org.xnio.nio                             : XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.6.Final
2016-08-25 01:02:47.743  WARN 21486 --- [           main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026009: XNIO worker was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default worker will be used
2016-08-25 01:02:47.744  WARN 21486 --- [           main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026010: Buffer pool was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default pool will be used
2016-08-25 01:02:47.753  INFO 21486 --- [           main] io.undertow.servlet                      : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-08-25 01:02:47.753  INFO 21486 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1332 ms
2016-08-25 01:02:48.125  INFO 21486 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-25 01:02:48.126  INFO 21486 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-25 01:02:48.126  INFO 21486 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-25 01:02:48.126  INFO 21486 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-25 01:02:48.127  INFO 21486 --- [           main] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2016-08-25 01:02:48.128  INFO 21486 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'authenticationTokenFilterBean' to: [/*]
2016-08-25 01:02:48.128  INFO 21486 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-08-25 01:02:48.283  INFO 21486 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-08-25 01:02:48.297  INFO 21486 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2016-08-25 01:02:48.339  INFO 21486 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.9.Final}
2016-08-25 01:02:48.340  INFO 21486 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-08-25 01:02:48.341  INFO 21486 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-08-25 01:02:48.366  INFO 21486 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2016-08-25 01:02:48.619  INFO 21486 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2016-08-25 01:02:48.789  INFO 21486 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2016-08-25 01:02:48.809  INFO 21486 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-08-25 01:02:48.886  INFO 21486 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/auth/login/'], []
2016-08-25 01:02:48.914 DEBUG 21486 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/auth/login']
2016-08-25 01:02:48.915 DEBUG 21486 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 'authenticated', for org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1
2016-08-25 01:02:48.919 DEBUG 21486 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Validated configuration attributes
2016-08-25 01:02:48.920 DEBUG 21486 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Validated configuration attributes
2016-08-25 01:02:48.922  INFO 21486 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@310d57b1, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@22cb3d59, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2407a36c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@29bbc391, com..security.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter@4c7e978c, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5cff729b, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5a7b309b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@143fefaf, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@28b8f98a, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6889f56f, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@6b867ee7]
2016-08-25 01:02:48.933 DEBUG 21486 --- [           main] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Validated configuration attributes
2016-08-25 01:02:48.996  INFO 21486 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@384ad17b: startup date [Thu Aug 25 01:02:46 HKT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-25 01:02:49.052  INFO 21486 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/auth/login],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com..web.AuthController.response()
2016-08-25 01:02:49.053  INFO 21486 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/secure/],methods=[POST]}" onto public com..model.Greeting com..web.MainController.homePage(java.lang.String)
2016-08-25 01:02:49.053  INFO 21486 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/secure/hello],methods=[GET]}" onto public com..model.Greeting com..web.MainController.greeting(java.lang.String)
2016-08-25 01:02:49.053  INFO 21486 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/secure/user || /secure/me],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com..web.MainController.user(java.security.Principal)
2016-08-25 01:02:49.055  INFO 21486 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-08-25 01:02:49.056  INFO 21486 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-08-25 01:02:49.092  INFO 21486 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-08-25 01:02:49.092  INFO 21486 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-08-25 01:02:49.122  INFO 21486 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-08-25 01:02:49.310 DEBUG 21486 --- [           main] eGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer : Eagerly initializing {webSecurityConfig=com..security.config.WebSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$12aaac67@47c40b56}
2016-08-25 01:02:49.312  INFO 21486 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-08-25 01:02:49.344  INFO 21486 --- [           main] b.c.e.u.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainer : Undertow started on port(s) 8080 (http)
2016-08-25 01:02:49.347  INFO 21486 --- [           main] com.BackendApplication   : Started BackendApplication in 3.256 seconds (JVM running for 3.461)
2016-08-25 01:02:57.681 DEBUG 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/auth/login'; against '/auth/login/'
2016-08-25 01:02:57.682 DEBUG 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /auth/login at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-08-25 01:02:57.682 DEBUG 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /auth/login at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-08-25 01:02:57.683 DEBUG 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /auth/login at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-08-25 01:02:57.684 DEBUG 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /auth/login at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-08-25 01:02:57.684 DEBUG 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2016-08-25 01:02:57.684 DEBUG 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/auth/login'; against '/logout'
2016-08-25 01:02:57.684 DEBUG 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2016-08-25 01:02:57.684 DEBUG 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /auth/login' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-08-25 01:02:57.684 DEBUG 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2016-08-25 01:02:57.684 DEBUG 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /auth/login' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2016-08-25 01:02:57.684 DEBUG 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2016-08-25 01:02:57.684 DEBUG 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /auth/login' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2016-08-25 01:02:57.684 DEBUG 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2016-08-25 01:02:57.684 DEBUG 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /auth/login at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter'
2016-08-25 01:02:57.684 DEBUG 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request '/auth/login' matched by universal pattern '/**'
2016-08-25 01:02:57.684 DEBUG 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] .a.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler : No failure URL set, sending 401 Unauthorized error
2016-08-25 01:02:57.684 DEBUG 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@3225c3b4
2016-08-25 01:02:57.685 DEBUG 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-08-25 01:02:57.686  INFO 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] io.undertow.servlet                      : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-08-25 01:02:57.686  INFO 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-08-25 01:02:57.697  INFO 21486 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 11 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://niels.nu/blog/2015/json-web-tokens.html) is slightly older (2015) and does not use Spring Security, but it is a JWT solution for securing a Spring Boot application. The author has also included their code on Github for reference, as you said the post you have been using is lacking in code examples.

Comment: It uses a different filter. I would have to change my entire filtering mechanism to accommodate this example.